# Specify namespace for new XElement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add new elements to an existing XDocument where the new XElement either specifies the namespace or is part of the default namespace.

I already have a XmlNamespaceManager and I can select elements using that.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsMgr.AddNamespace("default", "http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas");
nsMgr.AddNamespace("customNs", "http://custom.org");
```

Consider the following XML

```
<ROOT xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas" xmlns:customNs="http://custom.org">
    <ELM_1>
        <ELM_1_SUB_1>Some value</ELM_1_SUB_1>
    </ELM_1>
    <customNs:ELM_2>
        <customNs:ELM_2_SUB_1>Another value</customNs:ELM_2_SUB_1>
    </customNs:ELM_2>
</ROOT>
```

I'd like to write some code that would result in this:

```
<ROOT xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas" xmlns:customNs="http://custom.org">
    <ELM_1>
        <ELM_1_SUB_1>Some value</ELM_1_SUB_1>
        <ELM_1_SUB_2>ADDED TO DEFAULT NAMESPACE</ELM_1_SUB_2>
    </ELM_1>
    <customNs:ELM_2>
        <customNs:ELM_2_SUB_1>Another value</customNs:ELM_2_SUB_1>
        <customNs:ELM_2_SUB_2>ADDED TO CUSTOM NAMESPACE</customNs:ELM_2_SUB_2>
    </customNs:ELM_2>
</ROOT>
```

I have tried the following:

```
var elm1 = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/default:ROOT/default:ELM_1", nsMgr);
elm1.Add(new XElement("default:ELM_1_SUB_2", "ADDED TO DEFAULT NAMESPACE"));

var elm2 = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/default:ROOT/customNs:ELM_2", nsMgr);
elm2.Add(new XElement("customNs:ELM_2_SUB_2", "ADDED TO CUSTOM NAMESPACE"));
```

The above code does select the elements I want to add to with no issue but the Add throws an XmlException: `The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`.

When I try without the namespace provided in the element name I don't get an error but it doesn't do what I want.

So this:

```
var elm1 = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/default:ROOT/default:ELM_1", nsMgr);
elm1.Add(new XElement("ELM_1_SUB_2", "ADDED TO DEFAULT NAMESPACE"));
```

Results in this:

```
<ROOT xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas" xmlns:customNs="http://custom.org">
    <ELM_1>
        <ELM_1_SUB_1>Some value</ELM_1_SUB_1>
        <ELM_1_SUB_2 xmlns="">ADDED TO DEFAULT NAMESPACE</ELM_1_SUB_2>
    </ELM_1>
    <customNs:ELM_2>
        <customNs:ELM_2_SUB_1>Another value</customNs:ELM_2_SUB_1>
    </customNs:ELM_2>
</ROOT>
```

What am I missing to create the desired XML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `XNamespace` types with the desired values.
Use them when creating an `XElement`.

```
XNamespace defaultNs = "http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas";
XNamespace customNs = "http://custom.org";

elm1.Add(new XElement(defaultNs + "ELM_1_SUB_2", "ADDED TO DEFAULT NAMESPACE"));

elm2.Add(new XElement(customNs + "ELM_2_SUB_2", "ADDED TO CUSTOM NAMESPACE"));
```

Comment: Setting the `XNamespace` to a string and concatenating with a string threw me off a bit but it worked. Thanks.